# How can I run this bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This code works properly if I put it directly on cmd:

```
magick img.jpg -alpha Set -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,0,0 0,1900,0,1900 900,0,900,200 900,900,900,900' img_x.jpg
```

However, if I put this code in a bat file, it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
magick img.jpg -alpha Set -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,0,0 0,1900,0,1900 900,0,900,200 900,900,900,900' img_x.jpg
```

It gives this error:

```
magick: invalid list of numbers '-distort'
```

How can I do this. Thanks...

Comment: Based upon your response to the current answer, it seems clear to me that your properly working cmd example, is in fact untrue. If it works with single quotes in cmd.exe, the same would be true in the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for the `-distort` option needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
magick img.jpg -alpha Set -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective "0,0,0,0 0,1900,0,1900 900,0,900,200 900,900,900,900" img_x.jpg
```